# How to delete Document Link Properties

Tags: marklogic

I have some link properties in my document which is not getting deleted even after the removal of that linked document. I tried deleting with `xdmp:document-remove-properties`, but the "link" property is not getting deleted. The command I used is:

```
xdmp:document-remove-properties("/mydata/8632fcfa-3055-4d80-be88-fec3cfabefda.xml",
  fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/cpf/links","link")[28])
```

How to remove these link properties?

Comment: There is no function called xdmp:document-remove-properties. Maybe you mean dls:document-remove-properties.. Please provide a full sample of both code and a properties fragment. It will give people more to build a working example from.

Comment: Also, you are constructing a QName for link, but have a predicate selecting the 28th item (of which there will only be one), resulting in a call to delete no properties.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I last looked at CPF properties in detail, but I'd expect your links to be wrapped in an extra element. That wrapper would then be the document property, and the 28 links its child elements.

The function [xdmp:document-remove-properties](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-remove-properties) does exist, but only allows you to remove an entire document property (or multiple ones). It does not allow you to remove one specific element within one specific property.

You can remove it though, but you need to use [xdmp:node-delete](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:node-delete) instead. Something along the lines of:

```
xdmp:node-delete(
  xdmp:document-get-property(
    fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/cpf/links","links")
  )/link[28]
)
```

I haven't tested, but this should be close..

HTH!